# Block scoping in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Does the let keyword introduce alternatives to IIFEs for scoping?

Is the following valid syntax in ES6? I am intending to create an anonymous block with the brackets to scope the private variable `myPrivateVariable`.

```
let foo;

{
  let myPrivateVariable = 'x';

  foo = function(bar) {
    return myPrivateVariable + bar;
  };
}

//foo is now a function with access to a 'private' variable.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code runs just fine and does what's expected:

```
"use strict";

let foo;

{
    let myPrivateVariable = 'x';

    foo = function(bar) {
        return myPrivateVariable + bar;
    };
}

console.log(foo('y')); // xy
console.log(myPrivateVariable); // error
```

Tested with node v0.11.12, with the `--harmony` flag.

The whole point of IIFEs is to emulate block scoping, so, yes, `let` makes this trick not necessary anymore.